# How to invert the yAxis on eCharts without moving the xAxis?

Tags: echarts

I have a line chart made with [Apache eCharts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html).

The xAxis is days of the week. The yAxsis is a value from 0 to 100.

Currently my yAxsis has 0 at the bottom and 100 at the top.

It looks like this:

[image]

But I want the yAxsis to be reversed, so that 100 is at the bottom and 0 is at the top.

I have tried adding `inverse: true` to the yAxsis which does fix the yAxsis problem, but it also causes the xAxis to flip and move to the top.

Now looks like this:

[image]

How do I invert the yAxis without moving the xAxis?

Here is my code, with the `inverse: true` added to the yAxis:

```Javascript
const options = {
  xAxis: {
    data: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    type: 'category',
    name: 'Date',
  },
  yAxis: { min: 0, max: 100, inverse: true, type: 'value', name: 'Rank' },
  series: [
    {
      data: [10, 80, 28, 55, 19],
      type: 'line',
      smooth: true,
      lineStyle: {
        width: 3,
      },
    },
  ],
  tooltip: {
    show: true,
    trigger: 'item',
  },
  grid: {
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

On the yAxis I changed `min: 0` to `min: 1`.

Which causes the xAxis to stay in the correct place.

Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

And this is the full code:

```Javascript
const options = {
  xAxis: {
    data: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    type: 'category',
    name: 'Date',
  },
  yAxis: { min: 1, max: 100, inverse: true, type: 'value', name: 'Rank' },
  series: [
    {
      data: [10, 80, 28, 55, 19],
      type: 'line',
      smooth: true,
      lineStyle: {
        width: 3,
      },
    },
  ],
  tooltip: {
    show: true,
    trigger: 'item',
  },
  grid: {
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
  },
}
```

Comment: I changed the min value to 0.0001 which worked as well. Thank you for posting the solution.